# Issues with unsigned long long

Tags: c++, long-integer, unsigned

I was experimenting with the limits of an unsigned long long in C++ and ran into a bit of trouble. When I multiply 5 million by 5 million like this:

```
unsigned long long test = 5000000*5000000;
```

the variable `test` holds value 18446744072704921600 instead of 25000000000000. My understanding is that unsigned long long can represent 0 to 18446744073709551615, so what is going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default your compiler treats 5000000 as a 32 bit value. When you multiply the two together, you are still only working with 32 bit values, and so it will overflow. The conversion to 64 bit only occurs when the assignment is made to the left side of the equation.

The solution is to make at least one of the operands 64 bit to start with, e.g.:

```
unsigned long long test = 5000000i64*5000000;
```

Then the compiler knows to start with a 64 bit value and no overflow will occur.

Comment: I agree with everything here except that the compiler will treat 5000000 as a 32-bit value. The actual size is compiler and platform-specific. Otherwise, this is a great answer.

Comment: Correct, I should have said "your compiler" as clearly that is true in the OP's case.

Comment: Difference between that and `ULL`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Actually good point, I have a feeling that i64 is a Microsoft extension - I use it because I only code on Windows and I find it easier to see and understand than "ll". For portable code you would want `ll` or `ull`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: If your contention is ease-of-reading, consider `ULL` instead: Just uppercased.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that the right-hand side is doing the multiplication assuming the operands are `int`s, so you're getting an overflow. Try changing it to

```
unsigned long long test = 5000000ULL * 5000000ULL;
```

and see if that fixes anything.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
unsigned long long op1 = 5000000;
unsigned long long test = op1 * 5000000;
```